# Microsoft Sync Framework 'Expected column' error

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I've been using the `Microsoft Sync Framework` with no problems the last months, I added new columns to the database with no problems with the synchronization between my local database and my server database. Recently, I added some new columns to a tablet and I'm getting an error while synchronizing that specific table:

```
Expected column 'foo' was not found on the DataTable to be applied to the destination table 'MyTable'.
Parameter name: dataTable
System.ArgumentException: Expected column 'foo' was not found on the DataTable to be applied to the destination table 'MyTable'.
Parameter name: dataTable
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlChangeHandler.SetColumnOrder(DataTable dataTable, Int32& updateKeyOrdinal, Int32& createKeyOrdinal)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlChangeHandler.ApplyBulkChanges(DataTable dataTable)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.ApplyChangesInternal(DbSyncScopeMetadata scopeMetadata, IDbTransaction transaction, FailedDeleteDelegate_type failedDeleteDelegate, DataSet dataSet, ChangeApplicationType applyType)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.ApplyChanges(DbSyncScopeMetadata scopeMetadata, IDbTransaction applyTransaction, DataSet dataSet, DbSyncSession DbSyncSession, Boolean commitTransaction, FailedDeleteDelegate_type failedDeleteDelegate, String batchFileName, ChangeApplicationAction& action)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.SingleTransactionApplyChangesAdapter.Apply(DataSet dataSet, Boolean commitTransaction, FailedDeleteDelegate_type failedDeleteDelegate, String batchFileName, ChangeApplicationAction& action)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.ApplyChanges(DbSyncScopeMetadata scopeMetadata, DataSet dataSet, DbSyncSession dbSyncSession, Boolean commitTransaction)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.RelationalSyncProvider.ProcessChangeBatch(ConflictResolutionPolicy resolutionPolicy, ChangeBatch sourceChanges, Object changeDataRetriever, SyncCallbacks syncCallbacks, SyncSessionStatistics sessionStatistics)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeProviderProxy.ProcessChangeBatch(CONFLICT_RESOLUTION_POLICY resolutionPolicy, ISyncChangeBatch pSourceChangeManager, Object pUnkDataRetriever, ISyncCallback pCallback, _SYNC_SESSION_STATISTICS& pSyncSessionStatistics)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.CoreInterop.ISyncSession.Start(CONFLICT_RESOLUTION_POLICY resolutionPolicy, _SYNC_SESSION_STATISTICS& pSyncSessionStatistics)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWaySyncHelper(SyncIdFormatGroup sourceIdFormats, SyncIdFormatGroup destinationIdFormats, KnowledgeSyncProviderConfiguration destinationConfiguration, SyncCallbacks DestinationCallbacks, ISyncProvider sourceProxy, ISyncProvider destinationProxy, ChangeDataAdapter callbackChangeDataAdapter, SyncDataConverter conflictDataConverter, Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWayKnowledgeSync(SyncDataConverter sourceConverter, SyncDataConverter destinationConverter, SyncProvider sourceProvider, SyncProvider destinationProvider, Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.Synchronize()
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncOrchestrator.Synchronize()
```

I'm trying to download the entire table from the server to my local database. This always worked but now I suddenly get this error. I have the column `foo` in the table `MyTable` in both, my local database and my server database. What can be the reason behind this error?

Comment: I am stuck at same point. Any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution to this so I ended up creating a new database, running migrations and importing all the data from the old database. The problem seems to be somewhere in the migrations history of the database.

Answer (score 0):

when you provision a table, a corresponding UDF (TVF) is created to represent the table. This may have become out of sync with the base table when you run migrations.